# How to slim down Joomla for clients?

Tags: cms, joomla

I am just wondering is there a way I can create a 'lite' version of the admin backend, removing all the things my client wont need and just including things like article creation, web store stuff etc....

Comment: I don't know why someone would say this was too broad. First, the manager role already is a "lite" version of the backend with limited access. THen use the built in Access Control List system ("permissions") to allow or deny access tto the group